# What happens if 5 processes waiting in a semphore?

Tags: c, semaphore

Im using semaphore.h, what is happening if 5 child processes waiting on `sem_wait` while another child process unlocking the semaphore `sem_post`? Are they all going to be unlocked?

Comment: What's exactly the purpose of a thing which work is to prevent concurrent access to resources, that unblocks the access to that resource for multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: I want all of them to wait, but unblock specific one with its pid. How should I do that?

Comment: Why not use 5 semaphores, one for each child process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only one will be unblocked. RTFM.

[sem_wait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_wait)

[sem_post](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_post)

If many processes are block, then one will be chosen to be unblocked, which one is up to OS. Scheduler will choose one.

Comment: Which one is going to be unblocked?

Comment: @Bibrasnatho one of them :-)

Comment: with the power of randomness?

Comment: OS decides, the scheduler for example chooses one. @Bibrasnatho. I think you can not choose which one to wake up with this approach.

Comment: @Bibrasnatho You don't know. Even if you think you "observed" something, it might be different another day or with another version. If you need a sequence, you'll have to find a different solution.

Comment: With which approach I can choose which one?

Comment: I am not sure @Bibrasnatho. I am sure however that what you ask is another question. I would suggest you accept this answer, since the question is answered IMHO and ask a new question.

Comment: @Bibrasnatho You should probably create a new question, that provides more details what you need and why, what you have done, and how you know which pid is next.

Comment: @Bibrasnatho I gave you a +1 to your question, since you are new here. Make sure you search more before asking next time. :)